If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $a^3\mid b^2$ implies $a\mid b$
After writing this solution, I wanted to see if I could locate a post which might corroborate my attempt. The closest (in approach) I could find was Kell Berliner's solution (2nd soln from the top down) posted here. I wish to receive feedback on whether my solution correctly addresses XRBtoTheMOON's question regarding how we know $\sqrt{ca}\in\mathbb{Z}$ (written in my solution as $\sqrt{ak}$). I believe this can be accomplished with the following parity argument.
Proof Attempt:
[SETUP]
Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and suppose $a^3\mid b^2$. Hence $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ st. $a^3k=b^2$.
And thus, $a^2(ak)=b^2$. Or equivalently, $a\sqrt{ak}=b$.
We claim $\sqrt{ak}\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Simple analysis reveals that $a^3k=b^2\implies a(a^2k)=b^2\implies a\mid b^2$.
The FTOA (fundamental theorem of arithmetic) tells us that the right-hand side & the left-hand side of an equality must have the same number of each type of prime factor. In particular, the $\color{blue}{\text{LHS}}$ and $\color{green}{\text{RHS}}$ of $\color{blue}{a^2(ak)}=\color{green}{b^2}$ must have the same number of each prime factor. As the $\color{green}{\text{RHS}}$ is a perfect square, $a^2(ak)$ will necessarily have an even number of each prime factor in its factorization. There are two types of primes to consider in the factorization of $a^2(ak)$: those primes $p$ st. $p\mid a$ and those primes $p$ st. $p\nmid a$.
[PARITY]
$\underline{\text{Case 1:}}$
Consider a prime $p$ st. $p\mid a$. Such a $p$ will either appear an even or odd number of times in the factorization of $a$. If $p$ appears an even number of times in $a$, then it must also appear an even number of times in the factorization of $k$ (if it all). If $p$ only appeared an odd number of times in $k$, then there'd be an odd number of factors of $p$ on the $\color{blue}{\text{LHS}}$ & an even number of factors of $p$ on the $\color{green}{\text{RHS}}$, contradicting the FTOA. Since $p$ appears an even number of times in both $a$ and $k$, the product $ak$ will contain an even number of factors of $p$. If $p$ appears an odd number of times in $a$, then it must appear an odd number of times in $k$. Again, if $p$ appeared an odd number of times in $a$ but only an even number of times in $k$, then the $\color{blue}{\text{LHS}}$ would have an odd number of factors of $p$ and the $\color{green}{\text{RHS}}$ would have an even number of factors of $p$ contradicting the FTOA. No matter the scenario we're faced with, $ak$ will necessarily contain an even number of a given prime $p$ which divides $a$.
$\underline{\text{Case 2:}}$
Consider a prime $p$ st. $p\nmid a$, but $p\mid b^2$. As $p$ must be present in even quantity on the $\color{blue}{\text{LHS}}$, but is in no way contributed to the factorization of the $\color{blue}{\text{LHS}}$ through $a$, it must be that $k$ contains all those factors of $p$ (if such primes exist). Ergo, the product $ak$ contains an even number of factors of $p$.
Between cases 1 & 2, I believe this establishes that, regardless of the status of a given prime (i.e. whether $p\mid a$ or $p\nmid a$), it's true $p$ will appear an even number of times in the factorization of $ak$. This means $ak$ is a perfect square and hence $\sqrt{ak}\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.
As $\sqrt{ak}\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, this means $a\mid b$ as desired.
$\blacksquare$

This site is not a proof checking machine. Please check out the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

I think your proof is correct but the cases were not required. As $a^2ak$ is a perfect square and $a^2$ is also a perfect square, $ak$ is a perfect square which proves your claim.

@NagaSaiPrajith The statement "As $a^2ak$ is a perfect square and $a^2$ is also a perfect square, $ak$ is a perfect square" requires a proof.

$a^2\mid a^3\mid b^2\Rightarrow (a/b)^2 = n\in \Bbb Z\Rightarrow x^2-n,$ has rational root $,a/b,,$ so $,a/b\in\Bbb Z,$ by the linked dupes on irrationality of sqrts (which lead to almost every common proof known of such, including yours). Please search for answers before asking questions.
